# Unsuccessfully trying to get to the correct target_id

Tags: nodes

So I've been programming a module that needs to show different pictures depending on the language code of the user (en vs. fa). For that I'm trying to get to the right target_ids. Debug($nodes) shows me the following:

```
        [field_picture_active] => Array
            (
                [x-default] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 209
                                [alt] => Introdution
                                [title] => 
                                [width] => 320
                                [height] => 320
                            )

                    )

                [fa] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 241
                                [alt] => test222
                                [title] => 
                                [width] => 320
                                [height] => 320
                            )

                    )

            )
```

The correct target_id would be 241 under [fa] but when I try the following ...

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   $image_field = $node->get('field_picture_active')->first()->getValue();
   $fid = $image_field['target_id'];
}
```

... and then attempt to load the pictures for each nodes (or do debug($fid)), I just get the target_ids for each node that appear under [x-default] instead of [fa]. How can I access the target_ids under [fa]? Every other translation works perfectly fine, just those target_ids are not correct.

Any thoughts on this will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value for a specific language, you should use the translated node.
The following code should work

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  if ($node->hasTranslation('fa')) {
    $node = $node->getTranslation('fa');
  }
  $image_field = $node->get('field_picture_active')->first()->getValue();
  $fid = $image_field['target_id'];
}
```

If there is no translation, the default value will be taken.

Comment: Works like charm, thanks very much, good sir! With this, I even can combine the if-statement with the preferred user language code (or the site language code). Gorgeous!